# Trying to get specific fields using field_mask in Google Cloud document AI API request Python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, protocol-buffers, cloud-document-ai

I'm having this issue because i only want specific fields from the default JSON that returns [Google Cloud Document AI](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai). The fields i want to get using the field mask are: "text" and inside "pages" i just only want `tables` and `formFields`. For `text` `tables` i haven't got any issues doing the `field_mask` param in the request like this:

```
    # Configure the process request
    request = documentai.ProcessRequest( 
        name=resource_name, raw_document=raw_document, field_mask="text,pages.tables"
    )
```

The problem is only when im trying to access the fields inside "formFields" because i just want the marked fields i show in this image of the JSON:

[image]

I tried using `field_mask="pages.formFields.fieldName.textAnchor.content,pages.formFields.fieldValue.textAnchor.content"`
And when i do the request using Postman, the request take a long time with "Sending request" message and never returns anything.

I want to remember that this problem only happens when im trying to access a field inside "formFields", if i don't try this the request is successful so i think the problem isn't associated with how i do the request, i think is just im not using the correct syntax and i can't find any information or documentation about this. Thank you and advise me if you need more information or code.

Comment: Here's Google's documentation for [FieldMask](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.FieldMask). The only reference to repeated fields (like `pages`, `formFields`) is "A repeated field is not allowed except at the last position of a field mask." There appears (!?) to be no syntax to support retrieving child values (often refining the parent to be e.g. `[]` or `[*]`) or specific values e.g. `[0]`. Please try those variants but I think you may have to retrieve the entire repeated element (i.e. `pages`) and filter out-of-band.

Comment: As pointed out by @DazWilkin, Could you try retrieving a repeated field as last position of a field mask?

Comment: I tried using [ ] and doesn't work well, the solution we have implemented is retrieving the entire element (like "pages") and we have done a filter in Python to get the fields that we need. Is a valid solution for us, but i don't know why it can't be easier to do it directly in the field_mask. Thanks guys for the information @DazWilkin, Sakshi Gatyan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Documentation on [Field Mask](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.FieldMask) mentions,

> A repeated field is not allowed except at the last position of a field
> mask.

It looks like child values like "content"(in your JSON) cannot be retrieved directly using field mask. However, one can apply filters using client library to retrieve these child values.

Comment: The Documentation has been updated to show how to use a `FieldMask` in requests

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/send-request